# Ansible EC2 Region eu-central-1does not seem to be available for aws module boto.ec2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ansible

Im trying to do a simple Ansible script to attach a volume in EC2

```
- ec2_vol:
    instance: XXXXXX
    volume_size: 5
    device_name: sdd
```

When running I get the following error

> msg": "Region eu-central-1 does not seem to be available for aws
>   module boto.ec2. If the region definitely exists, you may need to
>   upgrade boto or extend with endpoints_path"

When I check that eu-central-1 is accesible via python boto... it is there:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> boto.ec2.regions()
[RegionInfo:us-west-1, RegionInfo:us-east-1, RegionInfo:ap-northeast-1, RegionInfo:ap-southeast-2, RegionInfo:sa-east-1, RegionInfo:ap-northeast-2, RegionInfo:us-east-2, RegionInfo:ap-southeast-1, RegionInfo:ca-central-1, RegionInfo:cn-north-1, RegionInfo:us-west-2, RegionInfo:us-gov-west-1, RegionInfo:ap-south-1, RegionInfo:eu-central-1, RegionInfo:eu-west-1, RegionInfo:eu-west-2]
```

Here are the versions of my tools

```
ansible 2.3.2.0
aws-cli 1.11.151 
Python 2.7.12 
Linux 4.4.0-93-generic 
botocore 1.7.9
boto 2.48.0
pip 9.0.1
```

I already check most of the things I can think of and even reproduce it on another virtual machine with vagrant and it gives me the same error..what else can I check?

Comment: try to install `boto` as well and test, you have `botocore` only

Comment: I have boto (2.48.0)

Comment: then show the complete playbook that you are running to get that error

Comment: Is a simple one: ```---
- name: Add volume
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  sudo: no

  tasks:
    - name: Attach volume to instance
      ec2_vol:
        region: "eu-central-1"
        instance: "i-0123456aaaaaaaaaa"
        volume_size: 10
        device_name: sdd```

Comment: Do you run this with `connection: local`?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks that was the issue... now it is working!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Do you run this with connection: local? – Konstantin Suvorov 6 hours
>   ago

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the comments:

> Do you run this with connection: `local`?

Cloud modules like `ec2_vol` are (usually) supposed to be executed from localhost (where all required libraries and credentials are stored).